# copy subfolder without parent folders

Tags: python-3.x, copytree

I have the folder `/a/b/c/d/` and I want to copy `d/` into destination `/dst/`.

However, `shutil.copytree("/a/b/c/d", "/dst")` produces `/dst/a/b/c/d`.

I only want `/dst`, or even `/dst/d` would suffice, but I don't want all the intermediate folders.

[edit]

As others have noted, copytree does what I want - I had unintentionally added the full path of the source to my destination!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this file structure (on my directory `/tmp`):

```
a
└── b
    └── c
        └── d
            ├── d_file1
            ├── d_file2
            ├── d_file3
            └── e
                ├── e_file1
                ├── e_file2
                └── e_file3
```

If you do `shutil.copytree("/tmp/a", "/tmp/dst")` you will get:

```
dst
└── b
    └── c
        └── d
            ├── d_file1
            ├── d_file2
            ├── d_file3
            └── e
                ├── e_file1
                ├── e_file2
                └── e_file3
```

But if you do `shutil.copytree('/tmp/a/b/c/d', '/tmp/dst/d')` you get:

```
dst
└── d
    ├── d_file1
    ├── d_file2
    ├── d_file3
    └── e
        ├── e_file1
        ├── e_file2
        └── e_file3
```

And `shutil.copytree('/tmp/a/b/c/d', '/tmp/dst')`:

```
dst
├── d_file1
├── d_file2
├── d_file3
└── e
    ├── e_file1
    ├── e_file2
    └── e_file3
```

`shutil.copytree` also takes relative paths. You can do:

```
import os
os.chdir('/tmp/a/b/c/d')    
shutil.copytree('.', '/tmp/dst')
```

Or, [since Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#standard-library-changes), you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) arguments to do:

```
from pathlib import Path
p=Path('/tmp/a/b/c/d')
shutil.copytree(p, '/tmp/dst')
```

Either case, you get the same result as `shutil.copytree('/tmp/a/b/c/d', '/tmp/dst')`

Answer (score 1):

that is what `shutil.copytree` does !

shutil.copytree recursively copies an entire directory tree **rooted at src** to a directory named dst

so the statement in the question :

`shutil.copytree("/a/b/c/d", "/dst")` produces `/dst/a/b/c/d`.

is just wrong.this will copy the contents of `d` (and subdirectories) in to `/dst`

Comment: @Tomerikoo exactly - I ment shutil.copytree.
hoosierEE- Your statement "However, shutil.copytree("/a/b/c/d", "/dst") produces /dst/a/b/c/d."  is just wrong. It does not.

Comment: Well I stand corrected... Indeed from my test also it produced exactly what you wanted @hoosierEE. It copies all contents of the directory into the `dst`. So you will get all contents of `d` inside `/dst/`, not even `/dst/d/`